# Are SX1276 DIOx pins necessary?

Tags: rf, lora, iot, sx1276

*This is about a [SX1276 Semtech](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001Rbr/6EfVZUorrpoKFfvaF_Fkpgp5kzjiNyiAbqcpqh9qSjE) chip dev custom board:*

For this project, is there anything missed when not connecting any of the DIOx pins to my microcontroller? I meant, in my project I have no pins available to connect to DIOx, which I'm leaving all six unconnected. Despite my software will suffer, am I missing something by not connecting them all, like lorawan stuff or any possible feature not accessible through SPI?

Comment: Have you read through the datasheet and application notes?

Comment: @JYelton yes, these pins as I see are only flags to avoid continuous reading through SPI

Answer (score 2):

The DIOx pin functions vary depending on the mapping mode. Are you using it in LoRa, Continuous, or Packet mode? The datasheet shows the various functions of these pins:

[image: LoRa Mapping Mode]

[image: Continuous Mapping Mode]

[image: Packet Mapping Mode]

You will have to determine whether any of these functions are things your software needs or not. Chapter 4 lists all of the registers, so you need to cross-reference these functions to see if any flags or data are only available via I/O pin.

Comment: some LoRaWan tutorials uses the DIOx (x = 0 to 2, commonly). Why is that? Is it needed for LoRaWan? 
(and still designing the hw, so I am not using Continuous nor Packet mode yet, but once I need to use them, my hardware needs to support both!)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a desensitization of RX due to continuous polling via SPI. So my rule is not to touch the chip if I can help it while it's in RX mode. Your mileage may vary depending on board design, SPI clock rate, SPI edge rate, etc.